# android in-app billing Trivial Drive

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, sku

I am making in-app purchases like TrivialDrive. Call queryInventoryAsync:

```
 mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

mGotInventoryListener:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        String price = inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_ALL_INCLUSILE).getPrice();
        Log.d("SKU", "price " + price);
    }
};
```

OnClick work perfectly and I can make purchase. But getPrice() method produces NPE. Help me please! I want to show SKU information in ListView.

SOLVED! Just use:

```
 mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, mGotInventoryListener);
```

Comment: I still don't understand why in Trivialdrive sample they use this line to get info: mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener); when you dive deep in this call you will find that it invokes the following: queryInventoryAsync(false, null, null, listener);  - and this will always return empty Inventory in listener callback! Why in the world they did that?!